# Angular 6 scope of this keyword is different in child components

Tags: angular, events, scope

I have a component, which we can call Profile-Main.
Profile-Main has the following data retrieval function:

```ts
getData(text: string): Observable<Response> {
    const baseUrl = environment.apiURL + "Profile/";
    const params = new HttpParams().set('userName', text);

    return this.httpClient
           .get(baseUrl + 'GetUser', {params: params})
           .map(response => <Response>response);
}
```

Now the Profile-Main Component makes use of angular input tags component(ngx-chips).
I am trying to implement the autocomplete feature which passes a ref to the getData function as follows:

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <tag-input class="tag-chips" [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Enter your User Name'"
                name="userName" [ngModel]="['Test User']" [maxItems]="1" [ripple]="false"
                [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true">

    <tag-input-dropdown [appendToBody]="false" [displayBy]="'Name'" [identifyBy]="'id'"
                  [autocompleteObservable]="getData">
    </tag-input-dropdown>
    </tag-input>
</div>
```

Now the issue is that when the `getData` method is hit, `this.httpClient` is undefined because at that point the scope of the `this` keyword refers to the `TagInputDropdownComponent` and not the `ProfileMainComponent`.

How do i get around this problem? I see that on the net there is alot of sources on input parameters but the problem with that is that I cant directly edit that npm package?

I'm new to angular 6 but there must be a simple way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you saying you can't edit the component that has getData function?

Comment: You can use `bind` to bind the context of `this`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are allowed to edit the component that has `getData` function, Try to use `Arrow` function syntax, it binds `this` automatically.

```
getData = (text) : Observable<Response> =>  {
    const baseUrl = environment.apiURL + "Profile/";
    const params = new HttpParams().set('userName', text);

    return this.httpClient
      .get(baseUrl + 'GetUser', {params: params})
      .map(response => <Response>response);
  }
```

Comment: Should be `(text) : Observable<Response> =>` if you want to use arrow functions I believe

Comment: Thank you, it's now working. Didn't know about this nifty trick.